# White texture showing in place of actual texture when not using dynamic memory in SFML

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml

I have an `Armor` class that stores a texture and a sprite to be drawn to the screen like such:

`Armor.h`

```
class Armor 
{
public:
    Armor(const std::string& armorName);

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);

    ~Armor();

private:
    sf::Texture armorTexture;
    sf::Sprite armorSprite;
    int numOfArmor;
};
```

`Armor.cpp`

```
#include "Armor.h"
Armor::Armor(const std::string& armorName)
{
    armorTexture.loadFromFile(armorName);
    armorSprite.setTexture(armorTexture);
    numOfArmor = 0;
}


void Armor::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    window.draw(armorSprite);
}

Armor::~Armor()
{
}
```

I also have an object called `Application` which stores an instance of `Armor` in a map, like such:

`Application.h`

```
class Application
{
public:
    Application();

    void start();

    ~Application();
private:
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    std::map<std::string, Armor> armorMap;
    std::map<std::string, Armor>::iterator armorIter;

};
```

`Application.cpp`

```
#include "Application.h"

Application::Application()
{
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application", sf::Style::Close);
    window.setFramerateLimit(120);

    std::string armorName;
    std::ifstream file("Armors.txt");
    while (file >> armorName)
        armorMap.emplace(armorName, Armor(armorName + "Armor.png"));
    file.close();

    armorIter = armorMap.begin();
}

void Application::start()
{
    while (window.isOpen())
    {

        sf::Event evnt;
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt))
        {

            if (evnt.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        while (armorIter != armorMap.end())
        {
            armorIter->second.draw(window);
            armorIter++;
        }
        armorIter = armorMap.begin();
        window.display();
    }
}

Application::~Application()
{
}
```

Whenever I construct the object, a white texture appears on the screen, which as I've found out is known as the [white texture problem](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php#the-white-square-problem). I was stumped because I'm sure my texture wasn't getting destroyed, so I decided instead to change the map to `std::map<std::string, Armor*> armorMap` and this fixed all my issues! Why would storing a pointer to an object of type `Armor` in the map work, but not the way I initially did it?

Comment: I think you're using the copy assignment operator when you are emplacing the items. I don't have any experience with SFML but it might not copy the texture properly. Which then causes the texture to be deleted when the object goes out of scope (as soon as you leave the line of emplacing).

Comment: In other words: if you use a pointer and assign that pointer via the `new` operator then your object does not get copied over into the map and the 'old' object does not get deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you store your armour object into the map you are making a copy of it, its texture and its sprite.

The sprite has stored your texture as a pointer to the original texture object which was destroyed (see https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a3729c88d88ac38c19317c18e87242560).

Storing pointers in the map will give you much better performance anyway as you will avoid the unnecessary texture copies. You should probably be using `std::shared_ptr<Armour>` rather than raw pointers unless you really know what you are doing.